# Intercept MS SQL query via MS SQL DB

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to intercept a query to a MS SQL database -> in a MS SQL database itself?

Goal is to implement custom security in MS SQL DB so that writing queries in the app stay simple.

#### Example

Instead of writing this in code

```
select top 1 
from Grades 
where 
    gradeId = 123 and 
    user_can_see_this_grade_logic_here
```

I'd just leave it like this

```
select top 1 
from Grades 
where 
    gradeId = 123
```

and leave the security to database itself, where DB would intecept this query and see that it's coming from the app or some exact user, and then it would check if that user can actually see that `Grade` or whatever else.

**NOTE**
I am not doing this via the app, because the security of the database should be implemented in the database, not in the app -> someone steals your db login credentials via your app, and he can do anything, unless the same security applies both to the app and the login parameters that the app is using.

So the focus in on intercepting queries in the MS SQL DB, checking the security / permissions, and returning only results that the user has permission to see / create / update / delete.

Comment: Sounds like [row-level security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security)?

Comment: I don't follow what you are really trying to achieve here, if I am honest. You can't *change* a query after it's been sent to the Data Engine, if that's what you are asking. But such requirements are normally a strong indication of an [XY Problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Seems it is a XY problem. I'll be reading row-level security now because that's what I was actually looking for. I didn't know that was already a thing.

Comment: That was a helpful read, and even though I didn't understand it 100% (I've understood it on a higher level, not as much in details) as im not that good with MS SQL DB, it has definitely given me a glimpse of how I could shift my view of the DB I want to create to be used with already implemented and faster security than what I had in my mind. Even though this is an XY problem, I would check the answer for 'How to intercept queries in MS SQL DB, via MS SQL DB?' as an answer to this thread.

Comment: Sounds like you want Row Level Security as mentioned, but note that it's not perfect and can have workarounds. Do not rely on it against a determined attacker, instead secure your database credentials properly. What exactly would be the `user_can_see_this_grade_logic_here`?

Comment: I wrote about [side-channel attacks here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4379/beware-of-sidechannel-attacks-in-rowlevel-security-in-sql-server-2016/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [performance impacts here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4778/performance-impact-of-sql-server-2016-rowlevel-security/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: Thanks Aaron! This helps me make an informed decision. I appreciate very much help from a veteran SQL dev! Charlieface, my goal with 'intercept sql requests in the db itself' was to not go the route of 'create db user for the app that can only see some stored procedures that all implement custom security', where 'custom security' would be adding a security column to each table and in it and storing what user can('t) see. This would rarely be done for individual rows, as the main rules would be stored elsewhere, not in each row for each user, but I'm researching 'user can see row' now.